# Connecting to MongoDB using Lithium li3 Framework

Tags: mongodb, lithium

I am writing a relatively simple app in the Lithium (li3) Framework.  I am using MongoDB as the datastore.  My MongoDB database is hosted in the cloud - at MongoHQ.

I am getting intermittent errors when trying to post data.  At times it will work - but then I will get an error that says the following:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with 
message 'connecting to mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@flame.mongohq.com:27052/DATABASENAME failed: 
Operation now in progress' in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php:257 Stack trace: 
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php(257): Mongo-
>__construct('mongodb://mongo...', Array) #1 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/Source.php(90): 
lithium\data\source\MongoDb->connect() #2 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php(160): 
lithium\data\Source->_init() #3 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/core/Object.php(93): 
lithium\data\source\MongoDb->_init() #4 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/Source.php(73): lithium\core\Object-
>__construct(Array) #5 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php(156): 
lithium\data\Source->__construct(Array) #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libra in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quizapp/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php on line 263
```

I am running this on MAMP on a Mac. I have tried to stop and restart Apache - but it does not seem to fix the problem.  However, I do seem to connect to MongoDB 1 out of every 10 to 15 attempts.  I cannot figure out any trends.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Nino

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer, but this discussion seems to suggest it may have to do with having a firewall enabled. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/9-DYhQWEo0E/B4UsY53S1IwJ  But maybe the connection between your Mac and MongoHQ is just too slow.  Maybe worth installing MongoDB directly on your Mac and only using MongoHQ when you throw is up on a server.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two possible issues here:

- A firewall, and a description to turn that off is at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/9-DYhQWEo0E/B4UsY53S1IwJ
- Slow connections — in some cases a connection to a host is too slow. And since version 1.3.4 of the Mongo PHP driver (which li3 uses) there is great control over timeouts. Have a look at the **timeout** option at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php — you will most likely want to increase that (but make sure you use 1.3.4 or later of the driver).

Comment: Thank you Derrick.   I added a simple "timeout" variable to my connection and this did the trick.

Comment: user1507531, I see you are now on StackOverflow. If you find that an answer has been properly answered, please click "accept" for it.